# QEMU Cannot Open Tap Device in Windows 10 Host

Tags: winapi, cross-compiling, device, qemu, file-not-found

I am trying to bridge my QEMU VM to a local adapter in my Windows 10 host, but QEMU complains that the interface name provided by `ifname` option to the `-netdev` argument cannot be opened. I have followed the answer in https://superuser.com/questions/1317652/how-to-set-up-nat-for-qemu-with-tap-backend-windows-10, but with no luck. I have cross-compiled QEMU from source to debug this behavior, for whether or not the interface name can be detected, and apparently QEMU can find the adapter's name, but not the TAP device file. To further explain my point, here's a code snippet from `net/tap-win32.c:595` from the QEMU 4.2.0 source code (latest release version as of this writing), specifically `tap_win32_open` function, and I will highlight where it was failing in this function (look for `// THIS IS WHERE IT WILL FAIL.` comments):

1. Testing with a correct existing network interface:

```
static int tap_win32_open(tap_win32_overlapped_t **phandle,
                          const char *preferred_name)
{
    ...

    rc = get_device_guid(device_guid, sizeof(device_guid), name_buffer, sizeof(name_buffer));
    if (rc)
        return -1;

    snprintf (device_path, sizeof(device_path), "%s%s%s",
              USERMODEDEVICEDIR,
              device_guid,
              TAPSUFFIX);

    handle = CreateFile (
        device_path,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        0 );

    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return -1; // THIS IS WHERE IT WILL FAIL.
    }

    ...
```

2. Testing with an incorrect (non-existent) network interface:

```
static int tap_win32_open(tap_win32_overlapped_t **phandle,
                          const char *preferred_name)
{
    ...

    rc = get_device_guid(device_guid, sizeof(device_guid), name_buffer, sizeof(name_buffer));
    if (rc)
        return -1; // THIS IS WHERE IT WILL FAIL.

    snprintf (device_path, sizeof(device_path), "%s%s%s",
              USERMODEDEVICEDIR,
              device_guid,
              TAPSUFFIX);

    handle = CreateFile (
        device_path,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        0 );

    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return -1;
    }

    ...
```

QEMU uses the prefix `USERMODEDEVICEDIR`, which is `\\.\Global\` and a suffix `.tap` to the device's GUID to create the device's path in Windows. For example, the network adapter I am dealing with results in the following device path: `\\.\Global\{990DA322-3986-4854-AE93-1D6FB0BFA137}.tap`. Any idea why `CreateFile` always results in `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on the device path? By the way, `GetLastError()` returns `2`, which from `learn.microsoft.com` means the following:

```
...
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

2 (0x2)

The system cannot find the file specified.
...
```

Comment: Try to use WinObjEx64 to see if the devices really exists

Comment: Make sure the path passed to `CreateFile` will be `"\\\\.\\Global\\{990DA322-3986-4854-AE93-1D6FB0BFA137}.tap"` if you use ASCII version API `CreateFileA`. And pass `L"\\\\.\\Global\\{990DA322-3986-4854-AE93-1D6FB0BFA137}.tap"` if you use unicode version API `CreateFileW`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize. I was attaching to a non-TAP adapter, thinking it will acquire the address from it, much like VirtualBox. I did not entirely understand the bridging concept before in QEMU, but now I should attach to a TAP adapter, and bridge that adapter to another preferred adapter.

Comment: If the issue solved you can share your solution and accept it.

Comment: Hi @RitaHan-MSFT, I have shared the solution to my issue. I was simply specifying a non-TAP adapter to the `ifname` sub-argument of the `-netdev` argument. Bridging in QEMU is more complicated than, say, in VirtualBox, where I can specify any adapter to bridge to.